# Rescue data using udev

Tags: linux, usb, data-recovery, udev

I have a device (Smartphone: BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu) which contains data, but I cannot reach it directly, i.e. mounting or opening a shell or alike.

All I managed to do was to see it (in fastboot mode) in `dmesg`:

```
[16357.747315] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
```

and with `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 020: ID 0bb4:0c01 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) Dream / ADP1 / G1 / Magic / Tattoo
```

and with `udevadm --debug monitor --udev`:

```
UDEV  [16997.275125] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2 (usb)
UDEV  [16997.277210] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0 (usb)
```

I don't see the device in `fdisk -l`.

**Is there a way to copy at least raw data, or even better access the file system?**

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this question will be moved to the android site. It has nothing to do with udev.

You'll need to install the [Android Debug Bridge](http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/) (ADB) tool and boot into [recovery mode](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/bq/bq-aquaris-e45-ubuntu-edition/recovery-mode/).

Once in recovery mode, you should be able to do a full backup:

```
$ adb backup -apk -shared -all
```

This should leave you a file called `backup.ab` which can be restored to another phone, or download [ADB Extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/) to recovery files from the backup.

Comment: Thank you. But `adb` is not possible. I cannot get the phone into developer mode, which is necessary for access via `adb`.

Comment: I'm not sure what "developer mode" is, but rescue mode definiltely supports ADB. Are you saying you can't get the phone to boot into recovery mode?